# IE condition CSS include

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-comments

Hy there...

I have a problem with Internet Explorer conditional comments...

I use this condition

```
<!--[if lte IE8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.bvp.hr/Static/Style/IEFix6.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

The problem is that in < IE8.0 i get output `<!--[if lte IE8]><![endif]-->` before any other output... Why?!? In Firefox it is rendered normaly (afkors).

Answer (score 6):

I believe all you need to do is add a space between `IE` and `8`, so it looks like this:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.bvp.hr/Static/Style/IEFix6.css"/> 
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

In the example above, theres a space between IE and 6. Just do the same for IE and 8:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.bvp.hr/Static/Style/IEFix6.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

See above plus the comments at the top of your code will force IE into Quirks Mode which will make the rendering of the page poor.  Remove these comments:

```
<!-- UUIDM component start --> 
<!-- Page generated by UUIDM component - part of WebSuite application platform. Copyright (C) Determinanta. All rights reserved. -->
```